# Infinite Subsets of Countable Sets

Tags: real-analysis

Does a subset of a countable set being infinite ALWAYS imply that the set of which it is a subset is also infinite?

i.e. $B \subset A $ , B is infinite $\iff$ A is infinite.

I know this is intuitively true, I'm just being super careful not to make false assumptions.

Comment: Yes. The cardinality of a superset is at least as large as the cardinality of any subset. But, it is not an if and only if. $A$ is not infinite only if $B$ is infinite. $\{1\} \subset \mathbb{N}$ is true, but $\{1\}$ is not infinite while $\mathbb{N}$ is.

Comment: So would you say B is infinite $\rightarrow$ A is infinite?

Comment: Yes, that implication is true.

Comment: Just take the contrapositive: if $A$ is finite is any subset $B$ necessarily finite?  That should be something you can have more confidence in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can think in infinite set $A$ when exist a map one to one

$$ g: \mathbb{N} \to A$$

If $B \subset A$ and B is infinite, then exist a map one to one

$$f: \mathbb{N} \to B$$

Now, take the inclusion map $\text{Incl}: B \to A$ where $\text{Incl}(x) = x$ and consider the composition $\text{Incl} \circ f: \mathbb{N} \to A $.
Thus, we say that A is infinite

By the other hand, if A is infinite, it is not always true that a subset of A is infinite.
@InterstellarProbe gave a good counterexample.